# SQL filtering entered data with same id but different date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

| product_id | total_product | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-03-04 14:37:24.580 |
| 1 | 21 | 2021-03-04 14:38:17.187 |
| 2 | 6 | 2021-03-05 10:26:38.513 |
| 2 | 17 | 2021-03-05 10:26:45.427 |
| 3 | 14 | 2021-03-05 13:27:45.540 |
| 3 | 32 | 2021-03-05 13:28:10.880 |
| 1 | 7 | 2021-03-05 17:38:19.260 |
| 1 | 44 | 2021-03-05 17:38:43.060 |

I have a table similar to the one above. I need to filter the data with the same product_id but entered on different dates according to the maximum number of production. I need an output like:

| product_id | max(total_product) | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 2021-03-04 14:38:17.187 |
| 1 | 44 | 2021-03-05 17:38:43.060 |
| 2 | 17 | 2021-03-05 10:26:45.427 |
| 3 | 32 | 2021-03-05 13:28:10.880 |

How should I create an SQL query? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: MySQL or Sql-server?

Comment: I am using ms-sql server

Comment: "select  product_id, max(total_product) as maxProduct from TableName group by product_id" 
I don't know how to separate by date. what i tried did not work

Comment: [edit] into your question.

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008? It's been completely out of support for 18~ months now; long past time getting that ugrade sorted.

Comment: Possible [dupe account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528675/how-to-filter-sql-same-id-but-different-values-and-dates?noredirect=1) (10K+ rep link).

Comment: When you say "by date" do you mean you want to also group by day (and not time) and return the latest time for each day?

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT product_id, MAX(total_product),DATE 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY product_id, DATE
ORDER BY product_id ASC;
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0276e6d8e6b3f733685ff97dfa374c49)

Comment: I tried the query but it brought all values ​​in the table

Comment: Isn't the result in the fiddle I provide is exactly like your expected output?

Comment: yes I was studying it right now. It gives exactly the result I want. But when I write the same query in sql-server, all values ​​are returned. Still, thank you for your help.

Comment: I realized I was missing a small detail. The table also has date and time data (such as 2021-03-05 13: 28: 10.880). that's why I can't get the results in sql-server as I want. Do you have any solution suggestions for this problem?

Comment: *"I tried the query but it brought all values ​​in the table "* Are you *sure* about that, @Beqs ? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f632f4d5d969a60aaabf73d5375dde7e)

Comment: In the date part of the table, the data comes as datetime, not as date (such as 2021-03-05 13: 28: 10.880). I'm sorry I forgot to mention this detail. @Larnu

Comment: I converted datetime to date, but could not find how to use it in the general query. can you help me? @FaNo_FN

Comment: How do you mean you've converted the datetime to date? In the table or from the query? Can you please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66526933/edit) with the details? Also have a look at this [updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3614f43fefbb27dd421ac02b84eaf007)